# second to the last transaction from each vendor

Tags: mysql, sql

I have transactions table, I need a list of only the second last transactions from each vendor, I'm using mysql5.7

```
Id customer_id order_id   transaction_date    status    vendor
1  BOB         TEST000001 2020-01-01          SHIPPED   Vendor BRO
2  JESS        TEST000002 2020-01-01          CANCELLED Vendor BRO
3  KAREN       TEST000003 2020-01-03          CANCELLED Vendor ALPHA
4  JESS        TEST000004 2020-02-04          CANCELLED Vendor CHARLIE
```

I have this so far, BUT INSTEAD it gives me literally the one row above of the last record (transaction) of each vendor.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id IN( SELECT MAX(id)-1 FROM transactions GROUP BY vendor );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vendor ORDER BY transaction_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM transactions t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In older versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.transaction_date = (select t2.transaction_date
                            from transactions t2
                            where t2.vendor = t.vendor
                            order by t2.transaction_date desc
                            limit 1 offset 1
                           );
```

Comment: I received Error Code: 1064 on line 3, is window functions not supported on mysql5.7?

Comment: @wingswingswings . . . Window functions are supported starting in MySQL 8+, which was released in early 2018.

Comment: I'm using 5.7, what other approach should I use on this one?